# jquery JSON php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
    echo "<div id='captionbox' style='width: 110px;float:left;color:#FFF;text-align:center;'>";
    echo "<a href='#' class='thumb'><img class='thumb-img' value = ".$row->aid." onclick='getVote(".$row->aid.", \"".$row->atitle."\")' src='images/roadies/th".$row->aid.".jpg' /> </a>";
    echo "<input  type = hidden name = aid id = rd".$row->aid." value = ".$row->aid.">".$row->atitle."</input>";
    echo "</div>";
}

$jsfriend = json_encode($data);
```

The above is my php code. i want the $data to be a JSON object. 
now i want to import it in my javascript file and use as a JSON object by using Jquery. But I am completely lost in the docs. there is a PHP example for doing things, but that includes some #id example i dont understand. can someone build me a Jquery function for this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT - What I am trying to do **
I am trying to get the JSON object jsfriend in to my javascript file, script.js. I dont know how to use the Jquery function. If someone could explain it. Also tell me once the JSON object is in the javascript, how do i access values from the JSON object?

**EDIT 2:
My JSON string reads like this:**

```
[{
  "aid": "1",
  "atitle": "Ameya R. Kadam"
}, {
  "aid": "2",
  "atitle": "Amritpal Singh"
}, {
  "aid": "3",
  "atitle": "Anwar Syed"
}, {
  "aid": "4",
  "atitle": "Aratrika"
}, {
  "aid": "5",
  "atitle": "Bharti Nagpal"
}]
```

Can someone tell me the Javascript if I want to display the name for aid:"1" ?

Comment: I don’t quite get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ignore the echo's. i am just trying to get the $data variable in my javscript so i can access it in JS.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You should modify your code to show only what you're trying to do, and include actual vs. desired output.  Are you simply trying to say `json_encode(mysql_fetch_object($result))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON string can be used directly in javascript.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var foo = '.json_encode($data);
echo 'alert(foo[0].column_name);';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Yet in few years when IE6 will be dead it would be much more secure to use `var foo = JSON.parse(data);`.